# UITabBarController in UINavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm trying to put an UITabBarController inside an UINavigationController (Programmatically), this is my code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
HomeViewPhone *home = [[HomeViewPhone alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
home.title = NSLocalizedString(@"HOME",nil);
EventiPhone *eventi = [[EventiPhone alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
eventi.title = NSLocalizedString(@"EXPLORE", nil);
FavoritiPhone *favoriti = [[FavoritiPhone alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
favoriti.title = NSLocalizedString(@"FAVORITES",nil);
ProfiloPhone *profilo = [[ProfiloPhone alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
profilo.title = NSLocalizedString(@"PROFILE", nil);
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:home,eventi,favoriti,profilo, nil]];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
```

but when I tap on one TabBarItem the app crash with this error

```
-[__NSCFString _tabBarItemClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7934db0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a note: according to Apple's guidelines, you should usually put navigation controllers inside tab bar controllers, not the other way around.

Comment: @iStopped Please can you define this how you solve this issue because i have stuck on same one :(

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Instead of

```
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
```

Then add navBarControllers to any of the tabs that need them.

Comment: @iStopped Are you in ARC?  Was the issue that the item was being released before you used it?  It's helpful to those searching if you could write up your solution and accept it.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

With ARC : solved with @property too !

More complicated app I have : AppDelegate -> NavigationController -> TableViewController -> TabBarController

First in AppDelegate, build the TableViewCtrl and insert in the NavCtrl

```
TableViewController *myTVC = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *myNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTVC];
[self.window setRootViewController:myNC];
```

Second, in TableViewCtrl method didSelectRow  (for my use), pushViewController to the TabBarCtrl

```
_myTBC = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:_myTBC animated:YES];
```

Last, property the TabBarController in .h : that's the key !

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITabBarController * TabBar;
```

and build the .m, do your own...

```
ViewController1 *VC1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
ViewController2 *VC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
_TabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSArray *table = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:VC1,VC2,nil];
[_TabBar setViewControllers:table animated:YES];
[[self view] addSubview:[_TabBar view]];
```

That's work nice! Doesn't need modal or other stuff...